# Django: Math on Models

Tags: django, django-models

I need to do some math against a value and I'm very confused about F(). I've read through the docs and searched for examples but I'm missing some fundamentals. Could you help with a solution and give some pointers about how to make sense of this? My attempts below are commented out. I'm just trying to convert Mb to GB. If I could get a 2 decimal value that would be be really wonderful.

```
class DatastoreInfo(models.Model):
    [ ... ]
    total_capacity = models.IntegerField(db_column='Total_Capacity', blank=True, null=True)
    [ ... ]
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Datastore_Info'


def ecsdatastores(request):
    form = myForm()
    results = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
         if 'listxyz' in request.POST:
             form = myForm(request.POST)
             taf = form['taf'].value()
             results = DatastoreInfo.objects.filter(f_hostname=c_name)
             # results = DatastoreInfo.objects.filter(f_hostname=c_name, total_capacity=F('total_capacity') / 1000)
             # results = DatastoreInfo.objects.update(total_capacity=F('total_capacity') / 1000).filter(f_hostname=c_name)
    return render(request, 'dpre/datastoreinfo.html', {'form': form , 'results': results})
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost are there. You need to organize your query so first you filter down to the applicable rows, and then you apply the update with the F function as the value.

```
# First take your filtered rows
results = DatastoreInfo.objects.filter(f_hostname=c_name)

# Then, on the filtered queryset, you can apply the update.
results.update(total_capacity=F('total_capacity') / 1000)
```

You can see this is just like the reporter example from the [Django F Expression Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).

```
reporter = Reporters.objects.filter(name='Tintin')
reporter.update(stories_filed=F('stories_filed') + 1)
```

Edit: As a side note you may want to divide by 1024, not 1000, if converting from GB to MB.

Comment: Thank you. I'm now at the point where I can get a calculated result without an error. However, I've found that each time I refresh (POST) the page, the calculation is performed against the last value AND it's written to the database. To avoid the repeating calculation I've tried both  within  `if request.method == 'POST'` and under `def ecsdatastores(request)` As for the writing to the results to the database, I'm overlooking something fundamental perhaps but I've no idea what that might be.

Comment: The trick is rather than displaying your results within a 200 response on the post, you actually have a separate View that displays your results, and use an HttpResponseRedirect (302, not 301) to then place the user on that results page, which they can refresh as often as they want without redoing the POST. You may want to consider using a FormView as well to further streamline your code.